# By road or on road

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence-construction, syntax, semantics

**She always travels by road.**
Is it correct to use the preposition *by* here because we use *by* normally with the means of transportation like **She always travels by bus.**?

Answer (score 4):

When discussing modes of transport - road, rail, air, land, sea, river, canal, etc, we use 'by'.

> In the UK, it is cheaper to travel by bus than by train. Travelling by
> air is usually more expensive, but quicker.

If we are discussing the type of vehicle or craft, we can use 'on' or 'in' before the word for the conveyance: a car, boat, ship, plane, bus.

> I am going to London in a car tomorrow. My mother came to my town on a
> train.

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions can be very ... flexible. You can say "travel by X" where X is a kind of vehicle, like "travel by bus", "travel by plane", etc. You can also say "travel by X" where X is the "medium" you travel through, like "travel by road", "travel by air", "travel by sea".

For that matter you could use "by" in a totally different sense, like "She always travels by herself".

They're all valid. Yes, clearly "by" does not mean the same thing in all these cases.